# Looping over two lists with conditional

Tags: python, python-3.5

Suppose I have two lists and from these two I want to create a third list which will contain a tuple of elements from the first list. In essence my code is like the following:

```
a = [3,6,7,8,12,89,289] 
b = [28,91,2489]
_max = 39
c = []
```

I want to iterate over the lists such that *if an element from list `a` is less than an element from list `b`* and *list `b`'s item - list `a`'s item <= `_max`*, then I will append the tuple to list `c`.

What is the best way to do this in python? I have been looking at `zip` function and similar functions but have not seen similar uses of it to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Your `list_a` and `list_b` are of different length.  Did you want to match first element to first element, second element to second element, and so forth?  Or did you want to match everything in `list_a` with everything in `list_b`?

Comment: So if we understand correct you want to loop over all pairs of elements from `a` and `b`: the Cartesian product.

Comment: I don't want to match everything. Only match if they meet the conditions. 

The lists are of different length due to the nature of the program. List a will always be longer than list b. If the conditions match for element in a with multiple elements in list b then I want tuples of those elements (then check conditions for the other elements in a against other elements in b).

Comment: Show the expected output.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski He wants to append the tuple `(a,b)` though not the difference `b-a`

Comment: "I want to create a third list which will contain _a tuple of elements from the first list_" it's not understandable the relation between this statement and the description of "I want to iterate over the lists such that if an element from list a is less than an element from list b and list b's item - list a's item <= _max, then I will append the tuple to list c.". In particular, with "I will append the tuple to list c", if you're talking about the tuple of elements from list a and b, then this is not the same thing as "a tuple of elements from the first list".

Comment: @StefanPochmann in my example it would return c = [(3,28), (6,28), (7,28), (8,28), (12,28), (89,91)]

Comment: @J.Doe Put that into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Since the wording of your original question is rather unclear, I assume you want to compare every element of list a to every element of list b. As has been pointed out in the comments, such a combination is called the *cartesian product*. If such a tuple fulfills your condition, you want to add it to your list c.

You can build your list `c` using a list comprehension with a condition:

```
a = [3,6,7,8,12,89,289] 
b = [28,91,2489]

max_value = 39

c=[(item_a, item_b) for item_a in a for item_b in b if (item_a<item_b and item_b-item_a<=max_value)]
```

Alternatively, you can use `itertools` to create the product:

```
import itertools
# ...
c=[(item_a, item_b) for (item_a, item_b) in itertools.product(a, b) if (item_a<item_b and item_b-item_a<=max)]
```

Also: please don't use the internal names (like `max`) as a variable names.

Comment: Would suggest to use `for item_a, item_b in itertools.product(a, b)`.

Comment: How can you answer to a question which is ambiguous in the description of the requirements or problem?

Comment: @nbro That's the way I understood his question. It is indeed not well written (_"tuple of elements from the first list"_), but I assumed that's what he meant. I will edit my answer to clarify my assumption.

Comment: I suggest to use  `abs(i[1]-i[0])<=max_value` in place  `(item_a<item_b and item_b-item_a<=max_value)`

Comment: @KHELILIHamza I think your expression is not equivalent, since (2,1) would be accepted, although 2<1 is false.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the zip function; that only looks at the pairs (element_a, element_b) where element_a is from list a, element_b is from list b, and both elements have the **same index** within the list.

What you want instead is to iterate over **all** pairs (element_a, element_b) where element_a is from list a, element_b is from list b.

This is called the Cartesian product of list a and list b.

There's a module for that (and lots of related iterations) -- itertools.

Specifically you want

```
from itertools import product
product(a, b)
```

You should use probably use a comprehension when you iterate over this, rather than building the answer up via appending.

Answer (score 0):

How about `itertolols.product`

```
[i for i in list(itertools.product(a,b)) if abs(i[1]-i[0])<=max_value]
```